# rpc eror whe using build comman in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I am using Docker desktop in windwos10. I have a docker compose file with 2 container (one with a simple python and and a mysql) when running the docker file (which is multistage) for the python app it works fine, but when trying to run it from the docker compose I get an rpc error, which I have been for one day trying to find a solution in the official docker forums (as I have been learning docker for just 2 weeks) and here but nothing I found it is working(I tried giving more memory to docker desktop, limiting the amount of memory each container use...). This is my dockerfile:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
      FLASK_RUN_HOST: 0.0.0.0
    mem_limit: 1GB
    networks:
      - app_network 

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: --init-file ./init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "admin"
      MYSQL_USER: "user-flask"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password123"
    mem_limit: 1GB
    volumes:
      - ./schemas:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    networks:
      - app_network 
volumes:
  schemas: {}
networks:
  app_network:
    name: app_net
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./myapp/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /code
RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local
ADD ./myapp .
ENV PATH=/root/.local:$PATH
ENV FLASK_APP App.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 3000
CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"]
```

and this is the output error I get:

```
#13 11.95 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#13 11.97   apk (no such package):
#13 11.97     required by: build-deps-20210215.104420[apk]
#13 11.97   add (no such package):
#13 11.97     required by: build-deps-20210215.104420[add]
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk update     && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev     apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev]: exit code: 3
```

Does anyone have at least a hint of where to look for? All I have found so far is related to giving more resources to Docker desktop and limiting the resources to the containers but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that you just lost `&&`  in the third line below

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev
```

Comment: sorry it was a copy paste error, in my original file it was ok I have updated it in the description above. So that it is not the cause

Comment: Strange, because an error msg to point to this error.
`apk (no such package):` - means that you try to add packages which called `apk`.
Maybe now you have another error? :)

Comment: ok so I tried to run just the dockerfile and run the container but I realized I get this error (just executing the dockerfile not docker-compose) ```MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, 'Plugin mysql could not be loaded: Error loading shared library /usr/lib/mariadb/plugin/mysql.so: No such 
file or directory')```